# CKEditor 4 not working due to error editor-incorrect-element

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor4.x

CKEditor 4 not working, getting this error: ([CKEDITOR] Error code: editor-incorrect-element. {element: "body"}   ckeditor.js:21 ).

My textarea has an id="body". I have added the script in the header. Everything is as it should be, but still not sure why it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

CKEDITOR.replace('body');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
```

The editor operates on `textarea` elements, so create one in your body somewhere:

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
```

Then initialize the editor with the following code **after** the declaration of your textarea element:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, before downloading the package I used CDN, was working fine. I have added this and seems to be working! Thank you. A question: can I add the replace script in the <head>?

Comment: Many thanks KUMAR.  I was doing everything you showed above ... but was initializing the CKEDITOR instance _before_ the form was sent.  Initializing CKEDITOR *after* the form was sent did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are calling same id or same class in other element before ckeditor textarea is called.

Eg.

```
<textarea class="editor_1"  id="editor_1"></textarea>
```

Check if same id or class is not called in any div above textarea

Eg.

```
<div class="editor_1" id="editor_1"></div>
```